# How to get proper user defined output when adding a string with a number, instead of NaN?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a Java Script program that should have two variables. You should add and display the sum only if they are numbers. If they are of any other type you should show a message "Sorry.... Only Nos will be added"
Please have look in the below snippet.
Thanks in advance

```
<script>
var x = Number(prompt("Enter First Choice"));
var y = Number(prompt("Enter Second Choice"));
var x1 = typeof x;
var y1 = typeof y;

if(x1==='number' && y1==='number'){
document.write(x+y);
}
else{
document.write("Sorry.... Only Nos will be added");
}
</script>
```

Comment: `isNaN` does the trick.

Comment: Use `Number.isNaN`

Answer (score 0):

Because `typeof NaN` is number. And `NaN === NaN` is `false` you should use `isNaN`.

```js
var x = Number(prompt("Enter First Choice"));
var y = Number(prompt("Enter Second Choice"));

if(!isNaN(x1) && !isNaN(y1)){
  document.write(x+y);
}
else{
  document.write("Sorry.... Only Nos will be added");
}
```

I short code will be like.

Comment: @Maheer-Thanks man...I got the point & it's working fine.

Comment: @Souradip Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied.